# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

На небе появляется удивительно яркий кроваво-красного цвета закат. Нужна запятая после яркий?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ЗАПЯТАЯ НУЖНА.**

Разделяет **согласованное** и **несогласованное** определения:

**"удивительно яркий"** -- согласованное определение;

**"кроваво-красного цвета"** -- несогласованное определение.

См. http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114 :

> **§ 39.** Запятая ставится при сочетании согласованных и
> несогласованных определений
> (несогласованное определение
> помещается после согласованного):
> *Между тем **в приземистой, с коричневыми стенами** зимовке Клюшиных
> действительно горела слегка увернутая
> семилинейная лампа* (Бел.); *Она сняла
> со стола **толстую, с бахромой**
> скатерть и постелила другую, белую*
> (П. Нил.).

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна. здесь ***яркий***  - уточнение.